# Fine-tuning parameters in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn

I am running a logistic regression with a tf-idf being ran on a text column. This is the only column I use in my logistic regression. How can I ensure the parameters for this are tuned as well as possible?

I would like to be able to run through a set of steps which would ultimately allow me say that my Logistic Regression classifier is running as well as it possibly can.

```
from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import pandas as p
loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f, 'r'), delimiter=' ')

print "loading data.."
traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:, 2])
testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[:, 2])
y = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:, -1]

tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3, max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',
                      analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', 
                      ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1, smooth_idf=1, 
                      sublinear_tf=1)

rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                           C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                           class_weight=None, random_state=None)

X_all = traindata + testdata
lentrain = len(traindata)

print "fitting pipeline"
tfv.fit(X_all)
print "transforming data"
X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)

X = X_all[:lentrain]
X_test = X_all[lentrain:]

print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

print "training on full data"
rd.fit(X, y)
pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
print "submission file created.."
```

Comment: Could you please explain better what you are trying to achieve? What hyperparameters are you trying to tune? Logistic regression does not have any hyperparameters.

Comment: @George Apologies for not being clear. I just want to ensure that the parameters I pass into my Logistic Regression are the best possible ones. I would like to be able to run through a set of steps which would ultimately allow me say that my Logistic Regression classifier is running as well as it possibly can.

Comment: @George scikit-learn's logistic regression takes several regularization parameters.

Comment: So it is not a logistic regression, but its a L1 or L2 regularized version?

Comment: @George  Logistic regression in scikit-learn also has a `C` parameter that controls the sparsity of the model.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use grid search to find out the best `C` value for you. Basically smaller `C` specify stronger regularization.

```
>>> param_grid = {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000] }
>>> clf = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(penalty='l2'), param_grid)
GridSearchCV(cv=None,
             estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, intercept_scaling=1,   
               dual=False, fit_intercept=True, penalty='l2', tol=0.0001),
             param_grid={'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]})
```

See the [GridSearchCv document](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) for more details on your application.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Can you please explain to me what the  C value does? I can find no specific information on this anywhere.

Comment: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599c1/13wi/slides/l2-regularization-online-perceptron.pdf  see the formula on page 3. The lambda is added as the regularization item. But in sklearn they divide the lambda in order to make the coefficient of sum of square of weight equal to 1. I guess they do this because they want to be consistent with the cost function in SVM.

Comment: I've been experimenting with Scikit-Optimize and it runs really quickly using a model based optimization.

Comment: @lennon310 Can we use C as 10 or 100 if my log loss is keep on improving?

Answer (score 5):

You may use below code for more general details:

```py
LR = LogisticRegression()
LRparam_grid = {
    'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
    # 'max_iter': list(range(100,800,100)),
    'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga']
}
LR_search = GridSearchCV(LR, param_grid=LRparam_grid, refit = True, verbose = 3, cv=5)

# fitting the model for grid search 
LR_search.fit(X_train , y_train)
LR_search.best_params_
# summarize
print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f' % LR_search.best_score_)
print('Config: %s' % LR_search.best_params_)
```

Comment: Please note that this code doesn't work, because there are illegal hyparam configurations. And for some baffling reason, sklearn silently fails instead of raising errors. Use `error_score='raise'` to view them.

Comment: I believe that your error does not straightly cause the code. Sometimes the type of data and data distribution can be the reason for some problems in computations.

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I think maybe the problem comes from the Hyparameter of "max_iter". Now works better. Can you do a double-check?

Answer (score 3):

Grid search is a brutal way of finding the optimal parameters because it train and test every possible combination. best way is using bayesian optimization which learns for past evaluation score and takes less computation time.

Comment: Would you please share some example source code for your solution? Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question and should be posted as a comment to the question.